# How to resolve to that discovery Service does not work: "failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes :<name:"txcc" >"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

When I use the SDK to query endorse for my chaincode, it occur error

> "error getting channel response for channel [mychannel]: Discovery status Code: (11) UNKNOWN. Description: error received from Discovery Server: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:"

when I execute the below command  in terminal, it occur "failed connecting to discovery service: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded"

```sh
./bin/discover --configFile conf.yaml peers --channel mychannel  --server peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

This is my configure.

```
services:
    ca.org1.example.com:
        container_name: ca.org1.example.com
        image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
        environment:
            - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
            - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
            - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
            - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
            - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_PKEY}
            - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
            - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_PKEY}
        ports:
            - "7054:7054"
        command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_PKEY} -b admin:adminpw -d'
        volumes:
            - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
        networks:
            default:
                aliases:
                    - ca.org1.example.com



    peer0.org1.example.com:
        container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
        image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
        environment:
            # - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
            #       # - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=172.31.159.129:5984
            - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
            - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=aberic
            - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
            - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
            - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
            - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
            - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
            - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true

            - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
            - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
              # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
              # bridge network as the peers
              # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
            - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=aberic_default
            - CORE_VM_DOCKER_TLS_ENABLED=true
              # - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR
            - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
            - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
            - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
            - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
            - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
        volumes:
            - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
            - ../examples/chaincode/go/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
            - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
            - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        command: peer node start
        ports:
            - 7051:7051
            - 7052:7052
            - 7053:7053
        networks:
            default:
                aliases:
                    - peer0.org1.example.com
        extra_hosts:
            - "orderer0.example.com:[A ip]"
            - "orderer1.example.com:[B ip]"
            - "orderer2.example.com:[B ip]"

    cli:
        container_name: cli
        image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
        tty: true
        environment:
            - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
            - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
              # - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR
            - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
            - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
            - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
            - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
            - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
            - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        volumes:
            - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
            - ../examples/chaincode/go/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
            - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
            - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
        depends_on:
            - peer0.org1.example.com
        extra_hosts:
            - "orderer0.example.com:[A ip]"
            - "orderer1.example.com:[B ip]"
            - "orderer2.example.com:[C ip]"
            - "peer0.org1.example.com:[A ip]"
            - "peer0.org2.example.com:[B ip]"
            - "peer0.org3.example.com:[C ip]"
```

Comment: I use Fabric-go-SDK

Comment: Who can help me !!!!!!

Comment: maybe the contract name is not the contract definition used in the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `--peerTLSCA tls/ca.crt` in the `discover` command. follow [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-cli.html) link for documentation

**SDK_GO**

1. Have you updated the `anchor peers`?
2. It would be great if you share the snippet of your code.

Comment: Hi, I am stuck at the same place, I did use ```--peerTLSCA tls/ca.crt``` in the ```discover``` command and I updated the anchor peer too. Still facing this issue:

```WARN Error - initializer returned error: load MSPs from config failed: configure MSP failed: sanitizeCert failed the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority. Will retry again later
Failed to commit transaction: Failed to submit: Discovery status Code: (11) UNKNOWN. Description: error getting endorsers: no endorsement combination can be satisfied```

Comment: Here is my entire code: https://pastebin.com/NUkcwuJD